Personal accounts on work machine
I often login into stackexchange or stackoverflow with my personal Google account and I've my Google account opened always in my work machine.
Should you do that and If not then please explain why not?

What are the risks? We can't answer that. What would happen if you make a mistake while stressed and use your personal account for business actions? What happens if company information winds up on your personal account?

(I am typing this at the office.)  Keep in mind that everything you type on the office computer is available to the company.  Don't type anything (or receive any emails) you would not want posted on the company bulletin board.  I can hear it now, "Oh, but it's https so it's encrypted." Since my company configures the software on my personal (company) machine, they can read all https traffic from my computer.  It is only private from the outside, to the company , it wide open.

I have a few personal accounts on my work machine. I want to check my personal e-mail, have a StackOverflow account and a few more. But not a lot.
In the end its a work machine, not a private machine. That IMO means there is a balance. In my case, as programmer, I want access to SO. I could make a work specific account, but I have a personal account that transcends a company. This is good for me (reputation) and for the company (a sortof library of things I fixed).
And the same goes my Spotify. I have music to help with focus. I could maybe make a specific one for work, but my account has my preferences. Good for me (my own music), good for company (they get 'free' extra focus from me).
I do not log in very personal sites, or if I do I log out instantly after the action. For instance: My Steam account is not logged in at work. It has nothing to do with my job and is unprofesional (gaming t your job is). Sometimes a colleage talks about a game which is interesting and I dont want to forget. I then log in, add it to my wishlist and log out. The absolute minimum.
So the answer to your question is: It depends.

Technically you should not mix personal and profesional at all. But in the real world there is IMO a small grey area.
Using personal accounts on a work machine poses a risk for you the user: If you get fired or leave and then dont have physical access to your machine, now what? Some company admin can now log in and see all your personal e-mail, maybe send an e-mail. Sure, most IT admins are decent, but do you want to gamble you're not the exception?
In my case my machine is only unlockable by myself, so that risk isn't there, but that does mean in most cases they need to provide access once so you can clear brower/accounts.

I know this is not the OPs question, but the there is also a reverse situation of work accounts on your personal machine.  This is exemplified by the Bring Your Own Device (BYOD).  So now you have company stuff on your device, and what is the expectation of that stuff when you and the company part ways.

Depends on your contract; some companies are fine with limited personal use on their equipment, others are not, especially if it's a highly regulated industry.
I would play very safe, and keep all personal stuff off the work machine; that way, they can't see it. Maybe even run a personal machine on the side for research and email.

To add some further potential risks:

What if someone gains access to your machine* and posts to social media from your account?  (Or even to StackExchange?!)
What if your machine has the only copy of personal passwords or other info, and you are fired or forget to retrieve them before leaving?

And for other types of personal use:

What if you store music, movies, or other copyright material on a company machine, and it gets discovered?
(And of course, it goes without saying that most employers would take a very dim view of their machines being used to access adult material.)

(* Maybe one day you step away from your machine without locking the screen, or someone guesses your password.  In any case, someone in IT probably has admin rights or some other way to gain access, and will use it if you leave, or for audits and other scans, etc.)
I think many employers are fairly relaxed about personal use provided it's fairly discreet: i.e. it doesn't take significant time or attention while you should be working, doesn't interfere with business at all, doesn't have any resource or security implications, and doesn't risk any legal liabilities.  But others are more strict — especially companies which are very big or (as another answer says) are in a heavily-regulated industry.
And even then, note that it's a privilege, not a right.  (Especially in these days when most people have smartphones they can use for most personal stuff instead.)
